# After debugging in xCode the previous version remain on the phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an app, already in the App Store and also installed on my phone from the iOS App Store.

When I build a new version in xCode and debug it on the device, it works well. But after I stopped debugging and close the application and start it again, the old version shows up (the version that I downloaded from the App Store).

I would assume that it can be a normal behavior (is it?), but if I delete the app, and start to debug (so xCode actually installs it again) after closing the app, I can see the old version again.

What is the solution? I want to see the newest, but not officially released version on my phone without using test flight, etc.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried resetting the simulator ?

Comment: I'm trying this on my iPhone. I guess a factory reset would help for my phone, but really don't want to do that :)

Comment: i missed the keyword "device" :)

Comment: This sounds very odd. Have you tried changing the version number before you build it in xcode?

Comment: yes, the version number is also different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: this issue is related to Bundle Identifier. We can't have two seperate apps with the same bundle identifier, because that's the unique identifier of an application. So the solution is the use a different bundle identifier for development and production purposes.